# HP DL360 G5 RAID controller not recognizing drive bays 5 and 6

Tags: debian, raid, hp, sas, hp-smart-array

I have an HP DL360g5 bios P58.  With a Slot 0, HP Smart Array P400i Controller (256MB v2.08)

The server originally was running Windows Server 2003 with 2 72GB 15k SAS drives in RAID0.  One of the drives failed and the system went down.  I'm rebuilding the server with Debian 7.8 and have gotten several 146gb 10k SAS drives to replace the others.

I've put 6 146gb 10k sas drives in bays 1-6.  But when I go to the disk volume manager and try to create a volume, it only recognizes drives in bays 1-4 (regardless of raid configuration).  No amount of swapping drives in bays gives me any more than recognition of the drives in bays 1-4.   Are bays 5 and 6 not for hard drives or not available to be used as part of a logical array?   Or do they require some additional controller?  I cannot find any reason why I shouldn't be able to use the drives in bays 5 and 6 either for part of the drive array or standbys.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Look inside your server. 
How many cables are connected between the RAID controller and the drive backplane?

[image]

If this server previously only used the first four bays, then it's likely missing the SAS cable needed to activate the 5th and 6th bays.

> To support drives 5 and 6, the optional HP Mini SAS 4i 13.4 inch/0.35
>   m cable is required (PN 399546-B21).

[See the DL360 G5 Quickspecs](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetHTML.aspx?docname=c04284194)

Comment: You sir are exactly right!   I'm missing this cable!   Thanks!

Comment: @MystMike Good. Does it work now?